# I'm tryng to render a "SectionList" in "React-native", but isn't working

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I'm new programing specially with React Native.I tryed to create a FlatList, it worked fine, but the data was not displayed as the away i wanted, cause i needed i header to organize the data as the away i wanted.I searched an i found the <SectionList> component. So i rewited the code to work, but when i put the the data, it shows me the due error:

```
(property) sections: readonly SectionListData<any, GamesInfoSection>[]
An array of objects with data for each section.

No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: SectionListProps<any, GamesInfoSection> | Readonly<SectionListProps<any, GamesInfoSection>>): SectionList<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'GamesInfoSection[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'readonly SectionListData<any, GamesInfoSection>[]'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'readonly SectionListData<any, GamesInfoSection>[]'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: SectionListProps<any, GamesInfoSection>, context: any): SectionList<any, GamesInfoSection>', gave the following error.
    Type 'GamesInfoSection[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'readonly SectionListData<any, GamesInfoSection>[]'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'readonly SectionListData<any, GamesInfoSection>[]'.ts(2769)
SectionList.d.ts(210, 3): The expected type comes from property 'sections' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<SectionList<any, GamesInfoSection>> & Readonly<...>'
SectionList.d.ts(210, 3): The expected type comes from property 'sections' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<SectionList<any, GamesInfoSection>> & Readonly<...>'
```

the full component:

```
 <SectionList

            sections={games}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (

              <View style={styles.game_section}>

                <View style={styles.game_match}>
                  <View style={styles.game_time}>
                    <Text>{item.games?.time}</Text>
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.breakLine}>
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.game_team}>
                    <View style={styles.team}>
                      <View style={styles.team_brand}></View>
                      <Text style={styles.team_name}>{item.games?.home}</Text>
                    </View>


                    <View style={styles.team}>
                      <View style={styles.team_brand}> </View>
                      <Text style={styles.team_name}>{item.games?.away}</Text>
                    </View>


                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.breakLine}>
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.score}>
                    <View style={styles.team}>
                      <Text style={styles.team_name}>{item.games?.homeScore}</Text>
                    </View>


                    <View style={styles.team}>
                      <Text style={styles.team_name}>{item.games?.homeScore}</Text>
                    </View>

                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>


            )}
            renderSectionHeader={({ section: { infoSection } }) => (

              <View style={styles.game_info}>
                <Text style={styles.game_country}>{infoSection?.country}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.game_league}>{infoSection?.league}</Text>
              </View>
            )}

          />
```

the data const:

```
const [games, setGames] = useState<GamesInfoSection[]>();

  useEffect(() => {

    try {
      const api = setupApiGames();
      api?.get('/games').then(response => {

        setGames(response.data);

      }
      )
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error + 'error ao acessar os Jogos');
    }

  }, [])
```

i tried to put the sugested solution by VScode:

```
  sections={games as any}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
```

But it doesn't work either , the error  disappeared, but the app don't display nothing, just a white page, removing even the components outside of the "SectionList"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an empty array which not conform with SectionList expected data structure:

Sample example data for SectionList:

```js
const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Main dishes",
    data: ["Pizza", "Burger", "Risotto"]
  },
  {
    title: "Sides",
    data: ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Fried Shrimps"]
  },
  {
    title: "Drinks",
    data: ["Water", "Coke", "Beer"]
  },
  {
    title: "Desserts",
    data: ["Cheese Cake", "Ice Cream"]
  }
];
```

`GamesInfoSection` type should conform with this data format.

Comment: thanks, yah, it was realy that, i had to format the data to the required type.

Comment: Cool. Glad it was helpful.